# Cannot change the text of Privacy and terms in woocommerce checkout

Tags: php, woocommerce

I have placed the following in functions.php

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_review_order_before_submit', 'ts_review_order_before_submit', 10 );
function ts_review_order_before_submit() {
?>
<script>
  // Check if the current page has the desired page ID(s)
  <?php if (is_page(array(32485, 25000))) : ?>
    
    // Check the locale or language of the page
    var locale = document.querySelector('meta[property="og:locale"]').getAttribute('content');

    // Function to update the checkbox label text
    function updateCheckboxLabel() {
      var checkboxLabel = document.querySelector('.woocommerce-form__label-for-checkbox span');
      
      // Update the text based on the locale
      if (locale === 'en_GB') {
        checkboxLabel.textContent = 'I would like to receive exclusive email messages with discounts and product information';
          
      } else {
        checkboxLabel.textContent = 'Θα ήθελα να λαμβάνω αποκλειστικά μηνύματα ηλεκτρονικού ταχυδρομείου με εκπτώσεις και πληροφορίες για τα προϊόντα';
          
      }
    }

    // Call the function when the page finishes loading
    window.addEventListener('load', updateCheckboxLabel);
  <?php endif; ?>
</script>
<?php
}
```

I am trying to change the text of terms checkbox. It changes for a second, but something else is running and it changes again to Greek as this is the first language when Woocommerce was installed.

Where can I place this script in order the text change according to page language?